# How would I completely reset network to after-fresh-installation status from Debian installer ISO?

Tags: networking, debian, boot

I need to completely reset my Debian VM's network side settings and configuration back to the state of a fresh installation. How can I do that with a Debian installer ISO? I was able to boot into rescue and launch a shell on /dev/sda1 and turn off the offender service (docker, where a container of `wg-easy` Wireguard service having `NET_ADMIN` capability on network `host` broke everything). But I have not been able to completely reset the network layer/side of things with the same approach. `iptables` command does not work in the rescue shell environment (I forgot what the error message was) and changing /etc/network/interfaces file does not seem to work - the file looked like a rescue environment copy rather than the installed Debian's copy. How should I go about resetting network's everything?

This is a VM and I am able to connect to its console using noVNC provided by the VM manager (Synology's Virtual Machine Manager). SSH does not work, pinging the IP address does not work. On my router's connected device list, there is not this VM despite correct MAC address binding to a fixed IP address. The rescue boot (single user mode) of the installation ends at the screenshot and I cannot interact with it except for a reboot with Ctrl+Alt+Del (noVNC's key combo, may not literally be that 3 keys).

[Screenshot of noVNC terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yorpc.jpg)

I could wipe this VM out and reinstall a fresh one. But what's the fun in that? Please help me get out of this weird state. Thank you!

Comment: A note on why you are not getting any reactions: Your whole problem is off topic here. This is a site for business environments and your case does not fall under reasonable information technology management practices, which is a requirement for this site. All your questions already got votes to be migrated to [unix.se], where it is better suited.